# "Do" in meaning of "learn"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the following sentence in the book "essential grammar in use" (Cambridge)

> "Jack **did** French at school but he **didn't do** German"

As I understand the meaning of the word  **"do"** can be as **'to learn'**. Is that correct?

I didn't see such meaning in the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do?q=Do).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the link you provide does list the learning meaning:

> *transitive* [UK] to study a subject:
>
> > Diane did anthropology at university.

So do [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/do_1), [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/do1_1?q=do), and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/do).

While marked [UK], this usage would also be found in the U.S., although I would be more likely to specify that he *took*, *studied*, *majored in*, or some such rather than *did*, and even more likely would phrase it as

> Jack did French at school, but not German.

---

*Do* is an extremely versatile verb, and can literally take the place of almost any other verb within a given context. *I did French* could mean a million things, however, so that context is essential: I put French dressing on my sald. I went to the French pavilion at the World's Fair. I installed a French drain in my backyard. I read a book about architecture by someone named French—or, I had sexual intercourse with him/her.

Comment: I think that the discussion of _do_ as a pro-verb, while accurate, is irrelevant and unhelpful in answering this question. The question was specifically about the lexical (not formal) use of _do_ to mean _study_.

Comment: @ColinFine Revised, also to reflect the updates to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The word "**do**" can have the meaning of "**learn**" or "**study**".

From [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/do):

> Do:
>   1.8 **Learn or study**; take as one's subject.
>
> ‘I'm **doing** English, German, and History’

Based on [Longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/do#do__15) this usege is typical for British English:

> **Do**: **study** [transitive] **British English**: to study a particular
>   subject in a school or university
>
> I **did** French for five years.

Based on [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/do) it's in spoken English:

> Do:  **If you** **do** a subject, author, or book, **you study** them at school or college. [spoken]
>
> I'd like to do maths at university. [VERB noun] 'So you did 'Macbeth'
>
> in the first year?'—'No, in the first year we did 'Julius Caesar'.'

Answer (score 1):

"Do" actually has at least a few dozen dictionary meanings, but you shouldn't feel that these are the only ones possible.  "Do" is one of those English verbs (like "get") that can be used to make up new phrases, the meaning of which you are expected to understand from the context.  For example,

> Roger doesn't **do** lunch.

Even if you've never heard this expression before, or you can't find anything related in the dictionary, you can still understand from context that the speaker means that Roger ordinarily does not *eat* lunch.

Another possible variation is:

> Roger doesn't **do** lunch breaks.

This means that Roger either doesn't personally *take* a lunch break, or he doesn't *believe* the *people he manages* should take lunch breaks. Again, in context, the meaning should be apparent.

For example, suppose you are talking to a professional chef, and you suggest you two get something to eat at McDonald's. The chef replies haughtily:

> I don't **do** fast food.

meaning she *strongly dislikes* eating a fast-food restaurants, and, presumably, prefers restaurants that take their time.

On the other hand, suppose she's cooking for you, and you suggest that you don't have a lot of time.  She might respond:

> I'm sorry, I don't **do** fast food

meaning that when she prepares food, she prefers to take her time, not rush.

Again, the point is that "do" has an extraordinary range of possible meanings, and you shouldn't limit it to only those you find in a dictionary.  Moreover you have to pay attention to context, since the *expected* meaning might be changed to something else, for humorous effect.

For example, since "do" can also mean "have sex with", I can make your example a little more risque:

> A: Jack did French at school but he didn't do German.
>   B: So he can speak French?
>   A:  No, not a word.  I mean he *had sex* with a French schoolmate but he never managed to get with that German he fancied.